# Why is $A^2$ halfway between $A$ and $A^\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Strang's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* 4e, question 5.1.19 (p. 280) asks:

[image: question]

It's clear that taking increasing powers of
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
.8 & .3 \\
.2 & .7
\end{bmatrix}$$

yields the convergent behavior shown, and I can also see that the eigenvalues of $A^k$ are $1$ and $2^{-k}$, with the latter going to zero as $k$ approaches infinity and the matrix becomes singular.

However, I don't understand the explanation Strang provides:

[image: answer]

There are plenty of matrices whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $.25$ that *don't* lie halfway between $A$ and $A^\infty$. Is there a more specific way to answer the question as posed: ***Why* does $A^2 = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^\infty)$?**

I'm assuming a full explanation rests on the fact that the eigenvectors for all powers of $A$ are the same (how do I prove this?), and somehow connects that to $A^k$'s convergent behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: diagonalise${}$?

Comment: That topic hasn't been introduced yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix $A$ has eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ with $Av_1=v_1$
and $Av_2=(1/2)v_2$. Then $A^2 v_1=v_1$, $A^2 v_2=(1/4)v_2$, $A^\infty v_1=v_1$
and $A^\infty v_2=0$. So
$$\frac12(A+A^\infty)v_1=\frac12(v_1+v_1)=v_1=A^2v_1$$
and
$$\frac12(A+A^\infty)v_2=\frac12(v_1+0)=\frac12 v_1=A^2v_2.$$
As every vector $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, then
$$\frac12(A+A^\infty)v=A^2v.$$

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: The second set of equations should be $$\frac{1}{2}(A + A^{\infty})v_2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}v_2 + 0\right) = \frac{1}{4}v_2 = A^2 v_2$$